# Archivo Markdown en GitHub

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, markdown

Estoy tratando de subir un archivo markdown creado en R, pero cuando lo cargo, el codigo aparece pero no las tablas ejecutadas.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente formula para resumir los datos: `head(daily_activity)`.
Asi me aparece en R:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi me aparece en GitHub:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido del archivo md es:

````
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```

    ## Data transformation and cleaning

    ```{r}
    library(tidyverse)
    library(skimr)
    library(janitor)
    library(here)
    library(chron)
    ```

    ```{r}
    dailyActivity_merged <- read.csv("G:/Otros ordenadores/Mi Portátil/Gaspar Facultad/Analisis de datos/Caso practico/Base de datos/dailyActivity_merged.csv")
    ```

    ```{r}
    sleepDay_merge <- read.csv("G:/Otros ordenadores/Mi Portátil/Gaspar Facultad/Analisis de datos/Caso practico/Base de datos/sleepDay_merged.csv")
    ```

    ### Selection of variables of interest.

    #### dailyActivity_merge

    ```{r}
    daily_activity <- dailyActivity_merged %>%
    select(-TrackerDistance, -LoggedActivitiesDistance)
    daily_activity <- daily_activity %>% 
    select(-Calories)
    ```

    ```{r}
    daily_activity <- daily_activity %>% 
    rename(ModeratelyActiveMinutes = FairlyActiveMinutes)
    ```

    #### dailySleep_merge

    ```{r}
    sleep_day <- sleepDay_merge %>% 
    separate(SleepDay, into = c("date", "hour"), " ")
    ```

    ```{r}
    sleep_day %>% 
    select(hour) %>% 
    filter(hour != "12:00:00")
    ```

    ```{r}
    sleep_day <- sleep_day %>% 
    select(-hour)
    ```

    ### Data type transformation.

    ```{r}
    daily_activity <- daily_activity %>% 
    mutate(ActivityDate = as.Date(ActivityDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y" ))
    ```

    ```{r}
    sleep_day <- sleep_day %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(date ,format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
    ```

    ### Cleaning

    ```{r}
    daily_activity %>% 
    filter(!between(ActivityDate, as.Date("2016-03-12"), as.Date("2016-05-12")))
    ```

    ```{r}
    daily_activity %>% 
    filter(VeryActiveMinutes > 1440 |
            ModeratelyActiveMinutes > 1440 |
            LightlyActiveMinutes > 1440 |
            SedentaryMinutes > 1440)
    ```

    ### Summary of the data.

    ```{r}
    glimpse(daily_activity)
    ```

    ```{r}
    head(daily_activity)
    ```

    ```{r}
    glimpse(sleep_day)
    ```

    ```{r}
    head(sleep_day)
    ```
````

Comment: Hello, we are in Stack Overflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Gracias por editar la pregunta. Ahora bien, podrías mostrarnos cómo se ve el archivo markdown en realidad? No cómo se renderiza sino el texto correspondiente, el contenido del archivo `.md`. No es evidente que esa datatable esté EN el archivo y no sea una intepretación de tu interfaz para r

Comment: Una cosa es Rstudio y otra Github, para renderizar tablas lo más simple es usar `kable()`: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html

Comment: No se si era a eso a lo que te referias, pero ahi edite la pregunta y pegue el contenido del archivo md.

Comment: ¿Si has realizado los pasos de configuración en GitHub y estás alojando la página en la URL proporcionada por este? Si no, aquí te dejo una [guía para alojar un MarkDown con R en una página de GitHub](https://mbounthavong.com/blog/2022/7/30/hosting-a-r-markdown-html-file-on-a-github-page) (en inglés)

Comment: Prueba hacer por ejemplo `knitr::kable( head(sleep_day))` y ver como se ve en github

Answer (score 1):

El formato por defecto de los repositorios de github no muestran los formatos deseados de las tablas de datos especializadas en **R** o **rstudio** aunque si podria servir usando **Github Pages**, tal vez estos pasos te ayuden. Necesitas crear 2 archivos, `index.rmd` e `index.html` luego te diriges a **rstudio** > knit > y ahí podrás generar el contenido html.

En el archivo `.rmd`:

````
---
output:
  html_document
---


Cargar librerias necesarias

```{r echo=TRUE}
#Load the libraries, if you don't have the library installed, run the following command per library:
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(DT) 


## Establecer datos y formato

```{r}
# Conjunto de datos: https://data.austintexas.gov/City-Government/Imagine-Austin-Indicators/apwj-7zty/data

austinData= fread('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgellis/MiscTutorial/master/Austin/Imagine_Austin_Indicators.csv', data.table=FALSE, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# formatear tabla
i1 <- austinData %>%
  filter(`Indicator Name` %in% 
           c('Prevalence of Obesity', 'Prevalence of Tobacco Use', 
             'Prevalence of Cardiovascular Disease', 'Prevalence of Diabetes')) %>%
  select(c(`Indicator Name`, `2011`, `2012`, `2013`, `2014`, `2015`, `2016`)) %>%
  mutate (Average = round(rowMeans(
    cbind(`2011`, `2012`, `2013`, `2014`, `2015`, `2016`), na.rm=T),2), 
    `Improvement` = round((`2011`-`2016`)/`2011`*100,2))
````

Mas información sobre tablas en **R** (ingles):

- [rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/](https://rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/)
- [lgellis.github.io/displayTables/](https://lgellis.github.io/displayTables/)